# Trying to merge 2 JSON documents using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I'm using JQ CLI to merge JSON from document to another. The issue I am facing is that I have select by the value of a property, rather than by a numeric array index

The first file contains a chunk of  JSON jqtest.json:

```json
{
  "event": [
    {
      "listen": "test",
      "script": {
        "exec": [],
        "type": "text/javascript"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The second file is where I want to merge the JSON into under "accounts" collection.json:

```json
{
  "item": [
    {
      "name": "accounts",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "Retrieves the collection of Account resources."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "accounts mapped",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "Retrieves the collection of AccountMapped resources."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What i am trying to do is merge it under "accounts" and under "name": "Retrieves the collection of Account resources." I use the command:

```sh
jq -s '
   .[0].event += .[1].item |
   map(select(.name=="accounts")) |
   .[].item
' jqtest.json collection.json
```

But when executed nothing is outputted. What am doing wrong with JQ or is there another tool i can use to accomplish this?

```json
{
  "item": [
    {
      "name": "accounts",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "Retrieves the collection of Account resources.",
          "event": [
            {
              "listen": "test",
              "script": {
                "exec": [],
                "type": "text/javascript"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "accounts mapped",
          "item": [
            {
              "name": "Retrieves the collection of AccountMapped resources."
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the output you expect? It's not clear what It's not clear what «*merge it under "accounts"*» means,  it's not clear what «*merge it under "accounts" and under "name"*» means, and it's not clear which of those two you want.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: I edited the question above question and added the desired output above

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the edit. (Either I didn't get notified because you didn't use `@ikegami` in the comment and/or because I was too busy with Christmas.)

Answer (score 0):

To merge two objects, one can use `obj1 + obj2`. From this, it follows that `obj1 += obj2` can be used to merge an object (`obj2`) into another existing object (`obj1`).

Maybe that's what you trying to use. If so, you were missing parens around the expression producing the object to merge into (causing the code to be misparsed), you have the operands to `+=` backwards, you don't actually produce the correct objects on each side of `+=` (or even objects at all), and you didn't narrow down your output (accidentally including jqtest in the output).

Fixed:

```sh
jq -s '
    ( .[1].item[] | select( .name == "accounts" ) | .item[] ) += .[0] | .[1]
' jqtest.json collection.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/62dEYxs2dD) on jqplay

I find the following clearer (less mental overhead):

```sh
jq -s '
   .[0] as $to_insert |
   .[1] | ( .item[] | select( .name == "accounts" ) | .item[] ) += $to_insert
' jqtest.json collection.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BZyHjPEcCW)

That said, I would avoid slurping in favour of `--argfile`.

```sh
jq --argfile to_insert jqtest.json '
    ( .item[] | select( .name == "accounts" ) | .item[] ) += $to_insert
' collection.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/i2vtE6YEH-) on jqplay