# jq concatenate arrays from two different files and save the output in the first file

Tags: jq

Here's what I'm looking to do.

file1.json

```json
{
  "info": {
    "id": "",
    "name": "Text Fields",
    "schema": "url"
  },
  "item": [
    {
      "name": "CompanyName Field",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "CompanyName is CompanyName1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

file2.json

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Phone Field",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "Phone is 1234"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Job Field",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "Job is Job1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected output after running jq

file1.json

```json
{
  "info": {
    "id": "",
    "name": "Text Fields",
    "schema": "url"
  },
  "item": [
    {
      "name": "CompanyName Field",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "CompanyName is CompanyName1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Phone Field",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "Phone is 1234"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Job Field",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "Job is Job1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As a first step I tried to at least concatenate the arrays of the two files and get that as an output before trying to get them in the first file itself but that itself is not happening.
Here's what I tried

```sh
jq '.item .' file1.json file2.json
```

but I get the following error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.item .
jq: 1 compile error
```

I tried searching a lot, trust me. There are a lot of queries with similar titles but they all seem to be very specific problems when you look into each one. Please help.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70396171/589924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--argfile` to read in the second file into a variable, then `+=` to add it to the existing array in `.item`

```sh
jq --argfile f file2.json '.item += $f' file1.json
```

```json
{
  "info": {
    "id": "",
    "name": "Text Fields",
    "schema": "url"
  },
  "item": [
    {
      "name": "CompanyName Field",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "CompanyName is CompanyName1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Phone Field",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "Phone is 1234"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Job Field",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "Job is Job1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How do I mark this as the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry but I actually don't know. I've never asked any questions here :(